# Handle IOException inside function

Tags: android, ioexception

I have a method which copies some files from shared memory to internal app memory using the library FileUtils.

The goal is handling IOException in order not to crash the app: it's acceptable if some files are not copied out of the total number.

In the second snippet below there is the called method where the exception is handled.

I need to know 2 things:

a) is there a way to handle the exception only in the called method
and **not also** in the calling code?

b) in your opinion the exception handling is correct or do I need to add some other code?

Below is the code:

```
try {
    copyfilesfromshared(context);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


public void copyfilesfromshared(Context context) throws IOException {

    for (int ii = 0; ii < numfiles; ii++) {
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(files[ii], dirwrite);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to handle the exception only in the called method and not also in the calling code?

If you handle the exception in `copyfilesfromshared()` function you do not need to declare `throws IOException`

```java
public void copyfilesfromshared(Context context) {
    for (int ii = 0; ii < numfiles; ii++) {
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(files[ii], dirwrite);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it normally, without declarin `try {...} catch(...)` again:

```java
 copyfilesfromshared(context);
```

> in your opinion the exception handling is correct or do I need to add some other code?

This looks fine to me, but better check the signature of `FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory` if it throws any other exception as well, you maybe want to catch here too.

Beside that, it is totally on your side where you wanna handle the exception, but in general the earlier the better.

Answer (score 0):

Heyy,

For your first question

> a) is there a way to handle the exception only in the called method
> and not also in the calling code?

There is a choise between throwing the IOException from the called method OR
to implement try/catch inside method.

And thats your problem
You are choosing both options instead of one, So just choose one.

And about 2 question

> b) in your opinion the exception handling is correct or do I need to
> add some other code?

Exception handeling is best at this moment, So don't think and other thought

And that's all!!